# Find the limits of the triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the limits for the triple integral where $E$ is the region below $z = 4 − xy$ and above the region in the $xy$-plane defined by $0 \le x \le 2$, $0 \le y \le 1$.

I have found the limits as:

$$2x \le z \le 5$$

$$0 \le x \le 2.5$$

$$0 \le y \le 10$$

The correct limits are:

$$2x \le z \le 5$$

$$0 \le x \le 2.5$$

$$0 \le y \le 10-2z$$

I don't fully understand the use of the $2z$ term in the $y$-integral. Why would my integral be wrong without the $2z$ term?

Also I was integrating as $dzdxdy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a typo in the question, I believe neither your limits nor the provided solution are correct.

First of all, $(x,y)\in[0,2]\times[0,1]$ means $0\le x\le 2$ and $0 \le y \le \color{red}{1}$. So the region $E$ is the set

$$E = \left\{(x,y,z) \mid 0\le x\le 2 \land 0\le y\le1 \land 0 \le z \le 4-xy\right\}$$

and hence the integral over $E$ (presumably to find its volume) is

$$\iiint_E dV = \int_0^2 \int_0^1 \int_0^{4-xy} dz\,dy\,dx$$

or in the given order of variables,

$$\iiint_E dV = \int_0^1 \int_0^2 \int_0^{4-xy} dz\,dx\,dy$$